# problem: how to verify affiliation of object in the collection of objects

Tags: python, lambda, iterator

I have a collection of objects. Objects are instance of the same class. I need to verify that the variable `reviewed_object_name` occurs in the `object_name` field of any object in the collection.

When I have a simple collection the solution is obvious:

```
reviewed_object_name = "Hotel Roma"
reviewed_objects_collection = ["Hotel Roma", "Hotel Berlin", "Hotel Paris", "Hotel Madrit"]

reviewed_object_name in reviewed_objects_collection
```

expression returns True

The problem arises when I have a collection of objects

I tried to do this using lambda:

```
some_function (reviewed_objects_collection, key = lambda review_object_info: review_object_info.name)
```

What function would be able to give me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) with a genex.

```
any(reviewed_object_name == reviewed_object.name for reviewed_object in reviewed_objects_collection)
```